# Can anybody tell me what is the output of the below C code?

Tags: c

According to me it has to print all the characters and their respective address but it is not the case.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char *name;
    int length;
    char *cptr;
    cptr = name;
    name = "DELHI";
    printf("%s\n",name);
    while(*cptr!='\0')
    {
        printf("%c-%d\n",*cptr,cptr);
        cptr=cptr+1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can!  Compile and run.

Comment: What does your compiler says??

Comment: Actually, nobody can. The code uses the value of uninitialized variables, so anything might happen.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck - most compilers will init pointers to null - so I'd expect an exception

Comment: @Hogan So would I. But you cannot depend on it. The actual output would depend on the system, but most of the output will probably be on `stderr`.

Comment: @all i am getting some random characters and their address as output, but no error or exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

This does not do what you think it does

```
cptr = name;
name = "DELHI";
```

Change it to this

```
name = "DELHI";
cptr = name;
```

Now you are happy.

In the first case you set cptr to point at where name was, then you point name to the constant.  cptr is pointing at some random location name is pointing at the constant.

In the second case they are both pointing at the constant.